# How to explode string column with CSV data in Hive 0.13.1

Tags: sql, hadoop, data-structures, hive

How to change data structure in table A?
It should look like table B.
I work in Hive 0.13.1

A

```
id                 |DATA
6ZE, FET, UZX      |50048
UZC, LQY           |89871
LQY, E03           |31579
HO7, 7KT, LXW, EK8 |17260
```

B

```
id  |DATA
6ZE |50048
FET |50048
UZX |50048
UZC |89871
LQY |89871
LQY |31579
E03 |31579
HO7 |17260
7KT |17260
LXW |17260
EK8 |17260
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trim(e.id) as id,t.data from t lateral view explode (split(id,',')) e as id;
```

---

```
hive> select trim(e.id) as id,t.data from t lateral view explode (split(id,',')) e as id;
OK
6ZE 50048
FET 50048
UZX 50048
UZC 89871
LQY 89871
LQY 31579
E03 31579
HO7 17260
7KT 17260
LXW 17260
EK8 17260
Time taken: 0.233 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)
hive>
```